How to correctly decode and parse base64-encoded Pyth price feed data on Solana?
I'm trying to decode and parse price feed data from the Pyth Network on Solana. The data comes as a base64-encoded string, but I'm having trouble converting this string into a meaningful number that represents the price.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

I decoded the base64 string into a binary format using Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64').
I attempted to parse the binary data, but I'm unsure how to correctly interpret the structure to extract the price.

This is a sample of the base64 string I'm working with:
'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'

Here is the rest of my code:
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import * as web3 from "@solana/web3.js";
import { PythConnection, PythHttpClient } from "@pythnetwork/client";
import { PriceServiceConnection } from "@pythnetwork/price-service-client";

describe("remove-liqudity", () => {
// Configure the client to use the local cluster.
const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
anchor.setProvider(provider);

const program = anchor.workspace.Holis;
const connection = program.connection;
const pythPublicKey = new 
web3.PublicKey("FswoDqTBxCt6tVLQi4osDyt9mf7KZzXybENQByak3fVt");

const tokenA = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
const sharesToBeMinted = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
const sharesTotal = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

...

it("Fetches BTC price", async () => {
    const priceServiceConnection = new PriceServiceConnection("https://hermes.pyth.network", {
        priceFeedRequestConfig: {
            // Provide this option to retrieve binary price updates for on-chain contracts.
            // Ignore this option for off-chain use.
            binary: true,
        },
    });

    // Hermes provides other methods for retrieving price updates. See
    // https://hermes.pyth.network/docs for more information.
    const priceUpdateData: string[] = await priceServiceConnection.getLatestVaas([
        "0xe62df6c8b4a85fe1a67db44dc12de5db330f7ac66b72dc658afedf0f4a415b43",
    ]);

    // Price updates are strings of base64-encoded binary data. Example:
    // ["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"]
    console.log(priceUpdateData);
    // Convert base64 string to Uint8Array
    const buffer = Buffer.from(priceUpdateData.toString(), 'base64');

    // Parse the binary data
    const priceData = parsePriceData(buffer);

    // Example function to parse the Pyth price data (This is an illustrative example 
    and might need to be adjusted based on Pyth's binary format):
    function parsePriceData(buffer) {
        // Assume the first 16 bytes are the price (this is just an example)
        const price = buffer.readBigInt64LE(0); // Reading 8 bytes as BigInt for 
    example
        const exponent = buffer.readInt32LE(8); // Reading the exponent (4 bytes as an 
    example)

        // Calculate the actual price based on the exponent
        return Number(price) * Math.pow(10, exponent);
    }

    // Use the parsed data
    console.log("Parsed Price Data:", priceData);

});

...

});

Can anyone guide me on how to correctly decode this data and extract the price? Are there any specific libraries or methods I should be using to handle the binary format?

It looks like Pyth provides a library for you to use at https://github.com/pyth-network/pyth-client-js/tree/main, and here's an example deserializing account data given a buffer:
      const base = parseBaseData(buffer)
      if (base) {
        switch (base.type) {
          case AccountType.Mapping:
            // We can skip these because we're going to get every account owned by this program anyway.
            break
          case AccountType.Product:
            const productData = parseProductData(buffer)
            break
          case AccountType.Price:
            const priceData = parsePriceData(buffer, currentSlot)
            break
          case AccountType.Test:
            break
          case AccountType.Permission:
            const permissionData = parsePermissionData(buffer)
            break

          default:
            throw new Error(`Unknown account type: ${base.type}. Try upgrading pyth-client.`)
        }
      }

Adapted from https://github.com/pyth-network/pyth-client-js/blob/1b9d17c7ba187b8ec445e921b3c268d365ce1f69/src/PythHttpClient.ts#L66
